# Rspec factory bot postgres UUID issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, factory-bot, uuid

I'm creating a user object using factory bot in an rspec feature spec.

The user belongs_to a company and has the below factory setup

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    company
    auth_token { Faker::Internet.password }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    contact_phone { '+353871234567' }
    status { true }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    password_confirmation { password }
  end
end
```

When I create a user via rails console the factory works as expected

```
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
```

The company is created and I can see the company_id as a UUID on the object

```
#<User id: "bb9fd4c7-bdce-4338-a42d-723876f514bc", company_id: "41e35b15-d766-4b1a-b833-bf1df4241064", first_name: "Frank", last_name: "Grimes", email: "drewshields@gislason.co"...
```

But when I use the same factory inside rspec feature spec both id and company_id fields are saved as integers not UUIDs

```
#<User id: 288, company_id: 0, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Deckow", email: "raleighharber@leannon.info"...
```

The user creation in rspec is below

```
let(:user) { create(:user) }
```

Is there any reason why rspec would have this effect?
Full feature spec below:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Specs for password reset
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'password reset', type: :feature do
let(:user) { create(:user) }
let(:invaliduser) {
    invalid = build(:user, first_name: nil, contact_phone: '123')
    invalid.save(validate: false)
    invalid
}

context 'active user resets password' do
    it 'sends an email to the user' do
        visit root_path
        first(:link, 'Login').click
        click_on 'Forgotten Password?'
        fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
        click_on 'Reset Password'

        expect(page).to have_content('If a matching email was found an email has been sent with password reset instructions.')
        expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to include(user.email)
        expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.subject).to include('Please reset your password')
    end
end

context 'inactive user resets password' do
    it 'sends an email to the {{__}} team' do
        visit root_path
        first(:link, 'Login').click
        click_on 'Forgotten Password?'
        fill_in 'Email', with: invaliduser.email
        click_on 'Reset Password'

        expect(page).to have_content('If a matching email was found an email has been sent with password reset instructions.')
        expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to include('{{team_email}}')
        expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.subject).to include('User Account Recovery')
    end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the same schema for development and test databases.
Easiest way to just drop and recreate testing DB

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup
```

Ensure that you have UUID type ids in `schema.rb`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Was banging my head against the wall on that one.